# Anomaly with qplot using two geoms; spurious unknown parameter error

Tags: r, ggplot2, syntax-error

I am working through Hadley Wickham's book "ggplot2" and find that some of his code does not work for me.If I run:

```
`qplot(carat, price, data = dsmall, geom = c("smooth","point"))`
```

I get exactly what I should: smoothed line with standard error shading plus individual points.

If I don't want the shading, I try:

```
 `qplot(carat, price, data = dsmall, geom = c("smooth","point"),se = FALSE)`
```

I get:

`Error: Unknown parameters: se`

But the parameter se miraculously becomes known if I drop the idea of "point":

```
`qplot(carat, price, data = dsmall, geom = c("smooth"),se = FALSE)`
```

yields a smoothed line without shading, just as it should.

What do I need to do to get points and smoothed line without shading?

I am using `ggplot 2.1.0`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using ggplot (supposing dsmall = diamonds) :

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = price)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(se = F)
```

Comment: Thanks for that but I was really looking for a qplot answer. Maybe the answer is just : don't use qplot.

Comment: [more complex plot requires ggplot()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322836/choosing-between-qplot-and-ggplot-in-ggplot2)